# Get values from objects in array with rest parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let newValues = user.info.socialMedia ? [...user.info.socialMedia] : []
```

So here we get several objects into the array that have an id key, and instead of the objects themselves I want to have only the id strings in this array. How can I get this working? I am quite new to Javascript, so it would be nice to get some help here.

I tried a for of then a for in loop to get the ids out of there and push them to the array, tho this does not work for my case.

Comment: It's always better to show what you have tried since there are different ways to do it and we'd like to teach you what was the problem with what you tried instead of just writing out a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> instead of the objects themselves I want to have only the id strings

That sounds like a `.map()` operation, to project one array into another by applying a transformation to each object.  Something like this:

```
let newValues = user.info.socialMedia ? user.info.socialMedia.map(s => s.id) : []
```

Or perhaps simpler:

```
let newValues = user.info.socialMedia?.map(s => s.id) ?? []
```

---

For example:

```js
let user = {
  info: {
    socialMedia: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Ron' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Tammy' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Tammy 2' }
    ]
  }
};
let newValues = user.info.socialMedia?.map(s => s.id) ?? []
console.log(newValues);
```

Comment: I like`(user.info.socialMedia || []).map(s => s.id)` a bit better instead, it's a single check. Having said that, I usually refrain from implementing something where the OP hasn't shown an actual attempt. Just a pointer to [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in the comments should be enough to help them.

Comment: ty, yeah I also tried mapping before, though somehow it resulted in bugs, but that had another reason, so I already knew the answer besides my attempt with the for loops, but still ty for answering since your response is correct